# object transparent in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, reflection

an object in my scene (actually multiple) are all transparent in render. this is because of the transmission box i have unchecked in the object properties tab

[image]

i have the box checked in order to not have it reflect off a glass pane in my scene

**transmission off**

[image]

**transmission on**

[image]

[warning, the blend file is 200mb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1umPiW0hOketdDM3uMyMtBrC61o4_yros/view?usp=sharing)

another thing to add, sometimes when you open the file, there is a very bright light that seems to be originating from the chair in the scene. my fix is to select everything (because some other models appear black or glitched) then go into edit mode and back into object mode

Answer (score 0):

Using a glass BSDF instead of a principled BDSF to portray glass fixed the issue.